# How to retrieve only the currency symbol without formatting a price expression from angularjs currency filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this span code in html:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">{{currency_symbol}}</span>
```

I am using localisation. So I am using i18n for angular. I am getting them correctly when I get the `{{price_expression | currency}}` i get the correct format with a price, but for this span I only need the symbol of the currency how can I get this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale) service

In your controller:

```
$scope.currency_symbol = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM;
```

But be careful!

> Each locale exists in its own file. These files are generated, with
>   very little human intervention from the Google Closure Library i18n
>   files.
>
> At a minimum they must expose an id. In general they expose a load of
>   other stuff such as number and date information. But Angular does not
>   guarantee that this is the case.

([Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11325))

So I suggest something like this:

```
$scope.currency_symbol = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM || '$';
```

Comment: Do i have to inject that on the controller right? the $locale ?